# Python and cyrillic alphabet

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ipython

I am working with an excel table using pandas through the ipython. Table contains cyrillic words. When I try to munge the data I am always getting strings of numbers instead of words. It looks like this:

```
In [16]: report_sorted_geo['country'].unique()
Out[16]: 
array([u'\u0410\u0431\u0445\u0430\u0437\u0438\u044f',
       u'\u0410\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043d',
       u'\u0410\u0440\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f',
       u'\u0411\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0441\u044c',
       u'\u0412\u044c\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0430\u043c',
       u'\u0413\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u043b\u0430',
       u'\u0413\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f',
       u'\u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0433',
       u'\u0413\u0440\u0443\u0437\u0438\u044f',
```

Is there a fix to this?

When I am simply trying to print something output is alright:

```
In [17]: print "привет"
привет
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: `u'\u0410\u0431\u0445\u0430\u0437\u0438\u044f'` is a unicode `str`, so it does contain a word, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Is there a way to make a word like this readable?

Comment: Well, it mostly depends of your intrepreter (it's a unicode string so maybe your interpreter does not "recognize" it)... Using `IPython (3.4) QT Console`, your code output words, if I run it using the Windows command line, I get the same output as you. What do you really want to do with these lines?

Comment: I want to munge the data, calculate some stats and create a pivot table. Would be quite hard to do, without able to read info in the table.

Comment: Note, I get the following in `IPython`: `array(['Абхазия', 'Азербайджан', 'Армения', 'Беларусь', 'Вьетнам', 'Гватемала', 'Германия', 'Гонконг', 'Грузия'], dtype='<U11')`, don't know if it is the expected output.

Comment: It is the exact output. I am not mac os, using anaconda.

Comment: @YKY: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? You _really_ need to mention that with Unicode questions, since the Unicode handing in  Python 3 is quite different from what it is in Python 2. FWIW, things like `'\u0410'` are called Unicode escape sequences.

Comment: Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:48:16) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org

Comment: Does `print u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'` produce `привет` in your terminal?

Comment: >>> print u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'
привет
>>>

Yes it does

Comment: You'll also find that `len(u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442')` is 6. So that string has 6 Unicode characters (codepoints) in it. In other words, everything's fine.

Comment: It is not fine. I mean technically yes, but I am not able to work with a table where there are numbers instead of letters. Is there a way to fix the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to convert your lists of strings to make them more readable in Python 2. This code explicitly encodes the Unicode data as utf-8 bytes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

data = [
    u'\u0410\u0431\u0445\u0430\u0437\u0438\u044f',
    u'\u0410\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043d',
    u'\u0410\u0440\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f',
    u'\u0411\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0441\u044c',
    u'\u0412\u044c\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0430\u043c',
    u'\u0413\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u043b\u0430',
    u'\u0413\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f',
    u'\u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0433',
    u'\u0413\u0440\u0443\u0437\u0438\u044f',
]

def list_to_utf8(seq):
    t = ["    u'%s'" % s.encode('utf-8') for s in seq]
    return '[\n' + ',\n'.join(t) + '\n]'

print list_to_utf8(data)
```

**output**

```
[
    u'Абхазия',
    u'Азербайджан',
    u'Армения',
    u'Беларусь',
    u'Вьетнам',
    u'Гватемала',
    u'Германия',
    u'Гонконг',
    u'Грузия'
]
```

---

To use this data in your Python code you **must** give a valid utf-8 encoding declaration at the top of the script, and you also must tell your text editor to save the file with the utf-8 encoding.

**test**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*- 

data = [
    u'\u0410\u0431\u0445\u0430\u0437\u0438\u044f',
    u'\u0410\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043d',
    u'\u0410\u0440\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f',
    u'\u0411\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0441\u044c',
    u'\u0412\u044c\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0430\u043c',
    u'\u0413\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u043b\u0430',
    u'\u0413\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f',
    u'\u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0433',
    u'\u0413\u0440\u0443\u0437\u0438\u044f',
]

newdata = [
    u'Абхазия',
    u'Азербайджан',
    u'Армения',
    u'Беларусь',
    u'Вьетнам',
    u'Гватемала',
    u'Германия',
    u'Гонконг',
    u'Грузия'
]

for s1, s2 in zip(data, newdata):
    print s1 == s2, s1, s2
```

**output**

```
True Абхазия Абхазия
True Азербайджан Азербайджан
True Армения Армения
True Беларусь Беларусь
True Вьетнам Вьетнам
True Гватемала Гватемала
True Германия Германия
True Гонконг Гонконг
True Грузия Грузия
```

Comment: thank you for the explicate answer. I will stick with the conversion function for now. Btw, if I decide to switch to python 3 in future will it help with unicode?

Answer (score 1):

Since your terminal supports it, why not just `print` each element of your array and let Python take care of the glyphs:

```
In [49]: for e in a:
   ....:     print e
   ....:     
Абхазия
Азербайджан
Армения
Беларусь
Вьетнам
Гватемала
Германия
Гонконг
Грузия
```

Comment: I will have to do so if I won't be able to find a better solution. I will have to massage this table for quite some time. And printing each record individually would be quite inconvenient.